# I can't get Vim navigation for the context menu

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have only seen example for navigation with IntelliSense, I want this navigation for the regular context menu.

I can pop the context menu with this binding:

```
{
    "key": "cmd+m", // whatever you chose here
    "command": "editor.action.showContextMenu"
},
```

I can navigate *IntelliSense* like this:

```
{
    "key": "j",
    "command": "selectNextSuggestion",
    "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
},
{
    "key": "k",
    "command": "selectPrevSuggestion",
    "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
},
```

But I can't find what the bindings are for up/down on the context menu (ie right click) or what the when condition would be (it's not codeActionMenuVisible).